# TypeError: The 'pid' argument must be of type number. Received an instance of Promise

Tags: javascript, terminal, vscode-extensions, pid

I am trying to create a VS code extension that extracts writes a command in terminal, executes the command, and then retrieves the output from the terminal. The terminal process does not seem to end thus unable to retrieve the output. When trying to kill the terminal process using "Process.kill(Terminal.ProcessID)" the error "The 'pid' argument must be of type number. Received an instance of Promise" pops up.
P.S. When I tried to kill the process inside of set interval no such error poped.

The terminal process seems to still exist.

```
function activate(context) {
  let terminal = vscode.window.createTerminal("Error Correction");
  terminal.show();
  terminal.sendText('python -c "print(1/0)"');
  console.log(terminal.processId);

  let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
    "error-correction.helloWorld",
    function () {
      console.log("terminal disposing");
      process.kill(terminal.processId);
      console.log("terminal disposed");

      console.log(terminal.processId);
    }
  );
}
```

I have tried to dispose the terminal which is working but still not killing the terminal.

Comment: Add your code directly into your question and then let us know what kind of output you're seeing from your current code, especially that first console.log statement.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/terminal-sample/src/extension.ts#L110

Comment: When running the code the error:
Command 'Hello World' resulted in an error ( The 'pid' argument must be of type number. Received an instance of Promise) Shows up

In the debug console:
Promise {[[PromiseState]]: 'pending', [[PromiseResult]]: undefined, Symbol(async_id_symbol): 2012, Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol): 1918, Symbol(destroyed): {…}}

terminal disposing